# format x-axis automatically

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a program can process different kinds of data. Some data are big and some are very small.
for some reasons I can only use matplotlib to plot figure as below:

```
      TimeDelta=FF.index[-1]-FF.index[0]          
      ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
      if TimeDelta>timedelta(days=6):
          intr=int(TimeDelta.days/6)
      else:
          intr=2
  #ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=(1),interval=intr))
      ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.DayLocator(interval=intr))
      ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b%d'))
      years= matplotlib.dates.YearLocator() # every year
      yearsFmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('')
      ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
      ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
```

I think this method is too complicated, Do someones have other simple method to deal with this situation?

Comment: Why do you think it is too complicated?

Comment: I wonder if there is a method like 'ax.xautofomat' or something I don't know that can format x-axis automatically.

Comment: @user1843099 - Have a look at `fig.autofmt_xdate()`. (Though it basically just rotates the date labels.)  Also, you're probably already doing it, but calling `ax.xaxis_date()` (or using `plot_date`) will set up the basic formatters for you.  Of course, what you're doing is a bit more fine-tuned, and the current state of the auto-formatters is far from perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are the `Auto*` classes in [`dates`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#module-matplotlib.dates) which do have some knobs you can tune, but you seem to a very specific formatting you want.  I would just make a function:

```
def my_x_axis_format(ax, dt):
    if dt>timedelta(days=6):
      intr=int(dt.days/6)
    else:
        intr=2
    #ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=(1),interval=intr))
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.DayLocator(interval=intr))
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b%d'))
    years= matplotlib.dates.YearLocator() # every year
    yearsFmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
```

and then you can make your figures as

```
TimeDelta=FF.index[-1]-FF.index[0]          
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
my_x_axis_format(ax, TimeDelta)
```